# migrating from devdept.eyeshot 6 to eyeshot 9

Tags: c#, migration, graphic, cad, eyeshot

I have a c# application in which is used devDept.Eyeshot 6 for its graphical design.right now I want doing a migration from devDept.Eyeshot 6 to devDept.Eyeshot 9.how is it possible? I even added the dll files of Eyeshot 9 in my references but I does not work yet.among you is there anybody who gives me another suggestion?
thanks in advance

Comment: There's no easy way when migrating from one framework to another, the same applies when upgrading some APIs to higher version. My suggestion would be for you to just branch your project and in that branch just remove all older references, add new ones and rewrite required parts of your solution keeping both version's documentations opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade from version to version using the instructions below and project converter (available from Eyeshot version 8).

1. https://www.devdept.com/Support/Migrating_From_6x
2. https://www.devdept.com/Support/Migrating_From_7x
3. https://www.devdept.com/Support/Migrating_From_8x
4. https://www.devdept.com/Support/Migrating_From_9x

**EDIT:** a new more comprehensive document is available [here](https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006817968-Migrating-from-Eyeshot-4-to-Eyeshot-10).

Comment: resolved the problem . actually with the solution that you wrote here.upgrading version by version and recompile and debug each version.for me project converter did not work very well . I did all the steps from 6 to 9 manually.the  most difficult step was upgrading from 7 to 8.